# wso2 api manager. redirect to localhost

Tags: wso2, localhost, wso2-api-manager

Please help
I installed wso2 APIM and now configuring. I created new REST API, and enter url "View in Dev Portal", redirected to localhost for me
I changed hostname in deployment.toml (ip-addr). Why redirecting to localhost for me?

Answer (score 4):

Uncomment and update this configuration.

```
#[apim.devportal]
#url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
```

Comment: This works. Make sure to also uncomment `[apim.devportal]`, that was my first mistake

Comment: How and where can i try this if i have a docker hub image (portainer) running already?

(running but redirects me to localhost instead of staying on my local ip)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Login to the Carbon console (/carbon) and go to Service Providers and select Store/Dev Portal as Application, and expand Inbound Authentication Configuration and click on edit. It will open the inbound authentication configurations, edit the callback URL by replacing the localhost with your IP/hostname and update it.

Now, the dev-portal will not be redirected to the localhost.

The same applies for the publisher as well.

Comment: I can not find any thing under Service Providers, it's empty

Comment: You have to first call https://localhost:9443/devportal URL so the entry appears.

Comment: @Prabakaran Answer is correct but miss some steps/flow for changing the callback URL that is confusing. here is the official troubleshooting of the error: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/